# Low Search loose_ends

Tags: low-search

Am i right in thinking

```
loose_ends="right"
```

Takes no notice of anything to the right of what you searched for?

Here is the matrix field i am searching.

[image]

Basically this would be an example search.

[image]

What i was hoping is that the [loose_ends="right"] would take no notice of the "HE" and return the entry with "LL28 3" in one of the rows but it doesnt at the moment.

In order for it to work i need to type "LL28 3" and submit the search. It will then return the entry.. is there a way that i can get it to work with the "HE" or whatever else letters is added after?

This is my code i have at the moment.

SEARCH:

```
 {exp:low_search:form result_page="search/results" form_id="postcodesearch"}
                <fieldset>
                    <label>Enter your postcode:</label>
                    <input type="search" name="keywords" placeholder="Enter your postcode here" class="postcode-entry" />
                    <button type="submit" class="white-button postcode-button"><span class="fa fa-search icon"></span>Search your postcode</button>
                </fieldset>
  {/exp:low_search:form}
```

RESULTS:

```
{exp:low_search:results query="{segment_3}" limit="1" collection="franchise" loose_ends="right" channel="franchise"}

    {if count ==  1}<ol>{/if}
    <li><a href="{comment_url_title_auto_path}">{title}</a></li>
    {if count == total_results}</ol>{/if}
    {if no_results}No search results{/if}

{/exp:low_search:results}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Am i right in thinking `loose_ends="right"` takes no notice of anything to the right of what you searched for?

No. To quote [the docs](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#keywords):

> `right`: lion will match lions and lionized.

...which means the search term *lion* will return entries that contain *lions* or *lionized*.

Based on your description, you're expecting the opposite: eg. *lionized* will also return *lion*. That wouldn't be desirable behaviour.

> is there a way that i can get it to work with the "HE" or whatever else letters is added after?

Only if you change the submitted keywords yourself, either with JavaScript on form submit, or using an extension which hooks onto [the low_search_pre_search hook](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/hooks#low_search_pre_search).

Comment: Thanks Low, wouldnt have the first clue how to go about that. Way over my head.  Would it be quick and painless for someone that knew what they were doing?

Comment: Depends on what the rules and formats for determining the post codes are. [Contact me](http://gotolow.com/contact) if you need a quote for such an extension.

Comment: Brilliant, I will do when I get back in work. Thanks.